# How can I create robot model and simulate with ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create my own robot model and simulate that with C or C++ code through ROS software.

But I can't find any information about that.

Please tell me about this problem detail.

I want to simulate like this vedio

[http://robotics.usc.edu/~ahoward/movies/gazebo-collide-15fps.avi](http://robotics.usc.edu/%7Eahoward/movies/gazebo-collide-15fps.avi)

Sincerely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9508/how-can-i-create-robot-model-and-simulate-with-ros?/) by [Aloe](https://answers.ros.org/users/320/aloe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The keyword you should look for is URDF (Unified Robot Description Format). This format along with the associated tools allows you to create a robot model and use it with existing ROS tools (for example gazebo, rviz and tf). Have a look at this page:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf
Be sure to click the "Tutorials" link in the light blue box, this should get you started.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-06**:
Just as an update... URDF replaced with SDF now.. For people reading through this thread now, make your models in SDF

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the Gazebo simulator with ROS:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo

The "Tutorials" link on that webpage has instructions for creating a robot in simulation and running it.

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1